# C++/cli: Cannot convert parameter 1

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, command-line-interface

I am trying to convert a C# code which works with a DLL into C++, so my c++ application can work with the DLL. So here I am developing a C++/cli application

I am working on this C# code:

```
private void SendUSBData(byte[] Data)
{
    if (this.USB.SpecifiedDevice != null)
    {
        this.USB.SpecifiedDevice.SendData(Data);
    }
}
```

`SendData()` is a method available in the dll. Following is it's definition in dll

```
public void SendData(byte[] data);
```

OK, now in my C++ code, I tried to convert C# code like this

```
void MissileLauncher::sendUSBData(unsigned char *data)
{
    if(usb.SpecifiedDevice!=nullptr)
    {
        //System::Byte
        usb.SpecifiedDevice->SendData(&data);
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I run this code

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CallToCSharp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  MissileLauncher.cpp
1>MissileLauncher.cpp(200): error C2664: 'UsbLibrary::SpecifiedDevice::SendData' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char **' to 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=unsigned char,
1>              dimension=1
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tried the following as well

```
void MissileLauncher::sendUSBData(array<System::Byte>^data)
{
    if(usb.SpecifiedDevice!=nullptr)
    {
        //System::Byte
        usb.SpecifiedDevice->SendData(&data);
    }
}
```

it gave me the following error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CallToCSharp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  MissileLauncher.cpp
1>MissileLauncher.cpp(125): error C2664: 'MissileLauncher::sendUSBData' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char *' to 'cli::array<Type> ^'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=unsigned char
1>          ]
1>MissileLauncher.cpp(159): error C2664: 'MissileLauncher::sendUSBData' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char *' to 'cli::array<Type> ^'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=unsigned char
1>          ]
1>MissileLauncher.cpp(164): error C2664: 'MissileLauncher::sendUSBData' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char *' to 'cli::array<Type> ^'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=unsigned char
1>          ]
1>MissileLauncher.cpp(166): error C2664: 'MissileLauncher::sendUSBData' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char *' to 'cli::array<Type> ^'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=unsigned char
1>          ]
1>MissileLauncher.cpp(186): error C2664: 'MissileLauncher::sendUSBData' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char *' to 'cli::array<Type> ^'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=unsigned char
1>          ]
1>MissileLauncher.cpp(188): error C2664: 'MissileLauncher::sendUSBData' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char *' to 'cli::array<Type> ^'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=unsigned char
1>          ]
1>MissileLauncher.cpp(200): error C2664: 'UsbLibrary::SpecifiedDevice::SendData' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cli::array<Type> ^*' to 'cli::array<Type> ^'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=unsigned char
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

How can I get rid of this?

### Update

As proposed in an answer, I tried the following code

```
void MissileLauncher::sendUSBData(unsigned char *data)
{
    if(usb.SpecifiedDevice!=nullptr)
    {
        int N = 10;
            cli::array<char>^ newData = gcnew cli::array<char>(N);

        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            newData[i] = data[i];

        //System::Byte
        usb.SpecifiedDevice->SendData(newData);
    }
}
```

Now, it is giving me the below error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CallToCSharp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  MissileLauncher.cpp
1>MissileLauncher.cpp(206): error C2664: 'UsbLibrary::SpecifiedDevice::SendData' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cli::array<Type> ^' to 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=char
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              Type=unsigned char,
1>              dimension=1
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

To be honest, I really don't know whether I coded this code correctly, as suggested.

Comment: Not going to start an edit war, but there was no reason to add tags back into the title. No need to duplicate what you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your data from `char*` to `cli::array<char>^`. The `cli::array` template is what implements `System::Array` in C++/CLI. To do so you need to know the length of the data:

```
int N = /* length of data */
cli::array<System::Byte>^ newData = gcnew cli::array<System::Byte>(N);
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    newData[i] = data[i];
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. i guess this is the code which should come inside the method. so, can i please know to which method you are referring? in my c++ code, i have showed 2 different attempts, using 2 different method styles, that's why

Comment: Where you do the conversion to `cli::array` isn't important, but instead that you follow the interface for `UsbLibrary::SpecifiedDevice::SendData`. This function expects a `cli::array<char>^` parameter so you need to pass the converted data as its argument.

Comment: please be kind enough to have a look at the edited code. please correct me if i have done something wrong.

Comment: My bad, there was an error in my original code. You need to use a `cli::array` of type `System::Byte`/`unsigned char`. Previously it was `char` which maps to the `System.SByte` .NET type. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Can you please help me in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580018/cannot-convert-parameter-1-from-systemspeechrecognitionchoices-to-syste

Answer (score 0):

Your second version was almost correct.  Here it is from the question:

```
void MissileLauncher::sendUSBData(array<System::Byte>^data)
{
    if(usb.SpecifiedDevice!=nullptr)
    {
        //System::Byte
        usb.SpecifiedDevice->SendData(&data);
    }
}
```

And here's the fix:

```
        usb.SpecifiedDevice->SendData(/* & <- take that out */ data);
```

Comment: @Knight: Did you take out the `&` like my answer says?  Also oops, I had copied your first version instead of your second version.  I was making a fix to your second version.

Answer (score 0):

by using the following code, convert c-style byte array to CLR byte array:

```
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

const char* from = xxxx; //(or unsigned char/signed char)
size_t length = strlen(from); 
array<System::Byte>^ target = gcnew array<unsigned char>(length);
Marshal::Copy((System::IntPtr)from, target, 0, length);
```